# Linking tkinter and sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm a new python programmer and I as creating a phonebook app using tkinter and sqlite3 but I faced a problem. The app runs without problem but not inserting or deleting data although it prints (inserted successfully) and deleted successfully). Please for you kind assistance. The code is below and thanks in advance:

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk 
import sqlite3

class Phonebook2:   
def __init__(self, master):

    lblName = ttk.Label(top, text="Name:")
    lblName.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky=W)
    lblPhone = ttk.Label(top, text="Phone number:")
    lblPhone.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

    self.name= StringVar()
    self.txtName = Entry(top, textvariable=self.name)
    self.txtName.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=EW, columnspan=19)

    self.num= IntVar()
    self.txtPhone = Entry(top, textvariable=self.num)
    self.txtPhone.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=EW)


    btnAdd = ttk.Button(top, text="Add", command=self.insert)
    btnAdd.grid(row=0, column=20, sticky=EW, padx=2, pady=2)
    btnDelete = ttk.Button(top, text="Delete", command=self.delete)
    btnDelete.grid(row=1, column=20, sticky=EW, padx=2)
    btnClear = ttk.Button(top, text="Clear", command=self.clear)
    btnClear.grid(row=2, column=20, sticky=EW, padx=2)
    btnSearch = ttk.Button(top, text="Search")
    btnSearch.grid(row=3, column=20, sticky=EW, padx=2)
    btnExit = ttk.Button(top, text="Exit", command = exit)
    btnExit.grid(row=4, column=20)


def exit(self):
    top.destroy()


def insert(self):

    NM = self.txtName.get()
    PH = self.txtPhone.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect ('Phonebook.db')
    print ("connection opened for insertion...")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute ("""INSERT INTO Phonebook (NAME, PHONE_NUMBER) VALUES (?, ?)""", (NM, PH))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print ('Inserted successfully')


def delete(self):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Phonebook.db')
    print ("Connection opened for deletion...")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute ("DELETE FROM Phonebook")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    print ("All records are deleted successfully...")


def clear(self):
    self.txtName.delete(0, END)
    self.txtPhone.delete(0, END)


top = Tk()
top.overrideredirect(True)
top.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
top.title("PhoneBook2")
application = Phonebook2(top)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your SQL statements seem OK.  Did you get any error in the console or terminal? Also post the schema of "Phonebook.db".

Comment: Inserting worked for me, after I create the Phonebook table in the database.

Comment: you have forget in your 'DELETE' your `entry.get()` and the sql `WHERE` . (If you want to delete specific items)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to INSERT like this:

```
query = ("INSERT INTO Phonebook (NAME, PHONE_NUMBER)""VALUES (%s, %s)")
    data = (NM,PH)
    cursor.execute(query, data)
    connection.commit()
```

Be sure to get the correct names of columns "NAME" and "PHONE_NUMBER" in your sqlite

Comment: sqlite3 uses `?` as placeholder, not `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def del_something():

    conn = sqlite3.connect("Phonebook.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("DELETE FROM phonebook WHERE oid = " + del_ent.get()) # <- change entry
    del_ent.delete(0, END) # clear entry

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: you can change the `oid`. this is only an example

Comment: Did you notice OP message inside `delete()` is *"All records are deleted successfully..."*? That means OP want to delete all records in the table.

Comment: None the less, the inputs are not sanitized.

Comment: so i don't know if it`s ok, I have the information from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9_gcIeAru0 (at 6min and 14:50) and it works for me. This with the oid was only an example. you can change it with anything else.

Comment: Well you shouldn't probably follow that video there, it is VERY bad to do like that. Your query is prone to SQL  injection. It should be `cur.execute("DELETE FROM phonebook WHERE oid = ?",(del_ent.get(),))`

Comment: I don't follow it. Atm I use mysql. But I tried these, a few months ago. But if you say, thats a bad suggestion (this vid), i think you know what you say. I have only posted these, for a suggestion.

Comment: With mysql, you dont use `?`, instead `%s`. The rest all is same. You can update your answer, with corrected code, if you want.

Comment: the code i posted is for sqllite3 (not mysql). So you needn't `%s`. Oh I see, I explained myself bad above, sorry.

Comment: Yes, you dont need `%s`, but you need `?`.

Comment: I can show you my old app if you want. I don't know if there are more "variants" in sqlite 3, but the delete works without `?` (with `get() method`). I tried it. I typed the Id and then delete button. it works.

Comment: It will definitely work, but it is not _safe_. Take a read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and understand. Never follow tutorials blindly, always check to see if it is the correct method. There are quite some mistakes in the video that you have sent. I also keep a watch in his tutorials and correct him if possible.

Comment: ah ok. In this case you mean that. Now it comes clear to me. Thanks. Nice to know, never heard about it before. So if it`s not sure what i posted, you can edit it, or if you want delete it for sure.